# macro for select all in vlookup

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

I format a large spreadsheet which changes weekly and match it with a data file that also changes weekly.  I need a "select all" function in my vlookup, as well as an "auto fill" to copy the formula down to the last row.  I've tried "CurrentRegion", "table", & failed miserably with "end" statements.  Since I rarely build macros, I don't have a large knowledge of VBA, but do enjoy learning.  I've received help on this site before and appreciate the time savings for work-related issues.  The codes I started with for this week are below, thank you!

```
ActiveCell.Select
Sheets("Demo").Select
Range("A2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[1],'Listing'!R1C1:R12182C4,3,FALSE)"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveCell.Range("A1:A177688")
ActiveCell.Range("A1:A177688").Select
```

Comment: You are going to have major performance issues using a vlookup on that many rows.

Comment: What do you recommend instead?  Is there another function?  It's only going to get larger every week.

Comment: There aren't enough details here to say.

Comment: Thanks anyway, I'll keep exploring for other options.

Comment: Happy to answer the question, but need some details. Where are you getting the data from? What version of Excel? What does the table look like? What does the lookup table look like? Where does the lookup table come from? What's the end goal for doing the lookup?

Comment: I download all of the data from our secured FTP site.  We have Excel 365, so the most recent version.  The table is a list of medical providers with all of their demographics.  Each provider is assigned to one of our Partners by Tax ID on Sheet2 of same workbook.  I'm trying to lookup which Partner is assigned to each provider each week.  Both data files increase in volume and the Tax IDs change "assignment" frequently.

Comment: Then I need to auto-fill down the column regardless of how many rows there are.

Answer (score 0):

i've made this macro that can select for you any cell that match a criteria of your desire that would be that select all function on your vlookup and it will also change the value of all selected cells according to your desire, but i need to know more about how the sheets looks like and what you're looking for in order to help you better, here is the code:

```
Sub selectall()

Dim rng     As String
Dim cname   As String

cname = InputBox("Enter column you wish to run the VLOOKUP", "NAME COLLECTOR")

'Change the "For" range as you desire to match the starting and ending line

For i = 1 To 100

If Range(cname & i) = "Enter what you're looking for" Then

If rng = Empty Then

rng = Range(cname & i).Address

Else:

rng = rng & "," & Range(cname & i).Address

End If

End If

Next

Range(rng).Value = InputBox("Enter the value or formula you want here", "NAME COLLECTOR")

End Sub
```